# How can I determine if a set of rows in one table (with a specific id) represents all of the rows in another table with the same id?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, relational-division

How can I determine if a set of rows in one table (with a specific id) represents all of the rows in another table with the same id?

I don't know how to create a query to determine whether or not I have a success case, as noted below.  I am trying to avoid using a WHILE loop in TSQL, and would much rather use a set-based operation.

Fail case:

Only 2 of the records in Table2 are represented in Table1.

Table1

| Table1_id | Table2_id | special_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 47 |
| 2 | 11 | 48 |

Table2

| Table2_id | special_id |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 45 |
| 11 | 46 |
| 11 | 47 |
| 11 | 48 |
| 11 | 49 |

Success case:

All records in Table2 are represented in Table1.

Table1

| Table1_id | Table2_id | special_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 45 |
| 2 | 11 | 46 |
| 3 | 11 | 47 |
| 4 | 11 | 48 |
| 5 | 11 | 49 |

Table2

| Table2_id | special_id |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 45 |
| 11 | 46 |
| 11 | 47 |
| 11 | 48 |
| 11 | 49 |

The expected result for my Success case would be the distinct Table2.Table2_id value 11.

Comment: Please post examples with created tables and what have you tried?

Comment: What have you tried? This isn't all that complicated and very similar questions have been asked many, many times.

Comment: join both tables, on table2_id and special_id and you know which are identical

Comment: What's wrong with a coorlated query and not exists Select * from table 2 where not exists in table 1.  or I suppose you could do a minus operation selecting both values from both tables... table 2 minus table 1; if you get results back you have records in 2 not in 1...

Comment: This is classic Relational Division.

Comment: [Is there any rule of thumb to construct SQL query from a human-readable description?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33952141/3404097)

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Comment: This is extremely unclear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. To describe a result: Say enough that someone could go away & come back with a solution & a user knows how to use it. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. [mre] PS Please do not put content only in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `LEFT JOIN` Table2 to Table1 and then `GROUP BY` table2_id, you can add a `HAVING` condition that compares the count of all Table2 rows with those having a matching Table1 row. If equal, all rows match and the table2_id can be included in the result.

Something like:

```
SELECT T2.table2_id
FROM Table2 T2
LEFT JOIN Table1 T1
    ON T1.table2_id = T2.table2_id
    AND T1.special_id = T2.special_id
GROUP BY T2.table2_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(T1.Table1_id) -- No unmatched rows
```

If your ID list came from another source and you needed to verify that all matching Table2 rows for each ID had matching Table1 rows, you could use a `NOT EXISTS()` test as follows:

```
SELECT T.id
FROM Ids T
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM Table2 T2
    LEFT JOIN Table1 T1
        ON T1.table2_id = T2.table2_id
        AND T1.special_id = T2.special_id
    WHERE T2.table2_id = T.id -- Current ID
    AND T1.Table1_id IS NULL -- No match
)
```

Note that the above will also pass if an ID has no matching Table2 rows. Since there are no Table2 rows, there are no *unmatched* rows, and the criteria passes. (Think of it like: *What are the prerequisites for a class? None? Then, the prerequisite criteria is always satisfied and anyone can get in.*)

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RYy1U13l) for a demo with some extra data.

Comment: Adding this comment to resolve this question.  I used the first approach that @T N suggested.  The piece/concept that I was missing in my code was the 'HAVING' syntax.  Thank you!